# How to call run-time linked function?

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking, loadlibrary

I have dll and I want to use a function from that dll in my project.
Dll and app project are in different projects (different IDEs).

Part of the dll (including shown below) code is generated with some code generator and I have little control over it.
dll code:

```
#define EXPORT_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

typedef  unsigned long       UINT32;
typedef  unsigned char       UINT8;
typedef  unsigned short      RESULT;

typedef struct VARIANT_s
{
  UINT32    Len;
  UINT8*    pData;
} VARIANT;

#pragma optimize( "", off )
EXPORT_API RESULT ExecuteV25 ( const UINT32 cmd
                           , const UINT32 inLen   , const char* const in
                           , const UINT32 inoutLen, const char*       inout
                           , const UINT32 outLen  , const char*       out)
{
  switch (cmd)
  {
    case 1:
    {
      VARIANT _odk_internal_variant_inout = {inoutLen, (UINT8*)inout};
      return func1 (_odk_internal_variant_inout);
    }
    case 2:
    {
      VARIANT _odk_internal_variant_inout = {inoutLen, (UINT8*)inout};
      return func2 (_odk_internal_variant_inout);
    }
    case 3:
    {
      VARIANT _odk_internal_variant_inout = {inoutLen, (UINT8*)inout};
      return func3 (_odk_internal_variant_inout);
    }

    default:
    {
    }
  }
}
#pragma optimize( "", on )
```

Dependancy walker shows:
[https://imgur.com/QPvPkLr][1]

In other project (in which i want to call function above) i have:

```
   typedef ODK_RESULT ( *_fpExecute) (  const ODK_UINT32 cmd
                        , const ODK_UINT32 inLen   , const char* const in
                        , const ODK_UINT32 inoutLen, const char*       inout
                        , const ODK_UINT32 outLen  , const char*       out
                                                    );
```

```
char* a     = new char[sizeof(_struc)]; //_struct size is ~19000 bytes
unsigned long a_size  = sizeof(_struc);
memset(a,  0, sizeof(_struc));


HMODULE hm = LoadLibrary("lib.dll");
_fpExecute _ExecuteV25   = (_fpExecute) GetProcAddress(hm, "ExecuteV25");
```

_ExecuteV25 = 1 after this. And than I try calling function with bellow line, but app crashes:

```
(_ExecuteV25) (1, 0,   nullptr, a_size, a , 0,    nullptr);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Most probably calling convention is different. Note that symbol `_ExecuteV25` is illegal.

Comment: Sanity and error check - does `LoadLibrary` succeed and return a valid `HMODULE`? Does `GetProcAddress` return a valid function pointer? Only then can you call it (assuming the correct calling convention as Slava points out). Is it valid to pass 0 and `nullptr` to the `in` and `out` parameters? Is `a_size` correct, ~19,000 bytes? Is `a` valid and non-null? Where exactly does it crash?